# In a contact Lie algebra, when is the Reeb vector a semisimple element?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, contact-geometry, coadjoint-orbit

Below is a question I have come across in my research, and it seems like a question that has been answered (or at least asked) in the past; however, I have been unable to find any references that mention it.

Background and Definitions:
If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a contact Lie algebra (of dimension $2k+1$), there exists some one-form $\varphi$ such that $\varphi\wedge(d\varphi)^k\neq 0,$ where $d\varphi(x,y)=\varphi([x,y]).$ Such a $\varphi$ is called a "contact form" on $\mathfrak{g}.$

Given a contact form $\varphi$ on $\mathfrak{g},$ a Reeb vector is the unique element $x_{\varphi}\in\mathfrak{g}$ defined by $d\varphi(x_{\varphi},-)=0$ and $\varphi(x_{\varphi})=1.$

Recall that an element $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ is called semisimple if it is diagonalizable.

**Question:

Under what conditions on $\mathfrak{g}$ does there exist contact form $\varphi$ whose Reeb vector is a semisimple element?**